# mysql get updated row info

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am new to mysql, i have a question like:

I have a table "user", it has a field named "age".

If I want to update all user with age > 10 to. how to print/get rows before update or after update?

I was wondering if there is something like this:

```
foreach(user in user_database){
 print(user); process(data);//process(user) with other process, not a mysql process 
  mysql_update(user);
}
```

after some research:

you can use SELECT ... FOR update.

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 select * from user where age > 10 for update;
  //here I can print(user) from above select
  //here I can process(user) from above select
 update ... where age > 10;
 COMMIT
```

This whole transaction scan the tale two times, one for select one for update, correct me if I am wrong here, is this the correct ways of doing it?

I need to gather what will be update from the update statement and I need to learn it and do it the right way.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `for update` clause locks rows and prevents other transactions from writing to them (and, in some cases, from reading). But it won't avoid a potential race condition: other processes can insert new rows where age > 10 between your two statements.

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step

First, before update just use

```sql
SELECT * FROM (your table);
```

Then

```sql
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2, ...
WHERE condition;
```

thats it.

Answer (score -1):

below should work

1. Select records where age is greater than 10

```
 Select * from user where age > 10;
```

2. Update records <<column_name>> is the name of column you want to update and <<new_value>> is the value you want to set.

```
Update user set <<Column_name>>=<<new Value>> where age > 10;
commit;
```

3. Select record post update

```
SELECT * from user where age > 10;
```